# (Syntax) Getting the index of the biggest difference between two lists (in 1 line)

Tags: python, list, loops, syntax

I know this can easily be done in a for loop, but I'm thinking there must be an intuitive way to do this in 1 line. For more explanation - you are given two lists, "juice" and "capacity". juice shows how much juice a certain index has and capacity shows the capacity of the index. I'm trying to find the index with the most remaining capacity. So I tried to do that by doing this:

`maxCap = max(capacity[i] - juice[i] for i in range (0, N - 1))`

But of course this doesn't save the index. How can I assign maxCap to the "i" which produces the maxCap as I have written?

Comment: Why does your title say "syntax"? Are you getting a `SyntaxError`? If so, please provide the _full_ error message, including traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
maxCap = max(capacity[i] - juice[i] for i in range (0, N - 1))
```

This same thing can be done simpler this way (although I don't understand the `N-1` part, so I am ignoring it):

```
maxCap = max(c - j for c, j in zip(capacity, juice))
```

Still, that gives the result, not the index. To find the index, `max` has to go through `i` values, rather than the calculated results, but maximise the results, like this:

```
max_index = max(range(N), key=lambda i: capacity[i] - juice[i])
```

On the other hand, if you are looking for efficiency, this is a good thing for `numpy`. If both `juice` and `capacity` are `numpy` arrays, then this can be done:

```
max_diff = (a - b).max()
max_index = (a - b).argmax()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `reduce`:

```
import functools
remainings = [capacity[i] - juice[i] for i in range (0, len(capacity) - 1)]
maxCap = functools.reduce(lambda acc, cur: acc if remainings[acc] > remainings[cur] else cur, range(len(remainings)), 0)
```

Reduce iterates over the iterable and returns a single result determined by the given reducer function.